# School District Boundary Optimization--Interpreting the Objective Function

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I’m looking for a little help on a new problem.  I’m in a linear programming class and trying to work on a project exploring methods on nonlinear optimization and I came across the following question in a book:

**Minimize the total distance traveled by students from $P$ subdivisions $N_j$ to determine the locations $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ of high schools $A$ and $B$**

minimize $$\sum_{j=1}^P w_{1j}\left((a-x_j)^2+(b-y_j)^2)^{1/2}+w_{2j}((c-x_j)^2+(d-y_j)^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Subject to $$\sum_{j} w_{ij}\le c_i$$

$$w_{1j}+w_{2j}=r_j$$

where $w_{1,j}$ is the number of students going to school $A$ and $w_{2,j}$ is the number going to school $B$, the capacity of school $A$ is $c_1$ and the capacity of school $B$ is $c_2$, and the total number of students in each subdivision is $r_j$, and the location of each subdivision is a single point $(x_i, y_i)$.

I understand the objective function and I think I could figure out how to solve the problem, but I’m a little confused about the variables.  It seems clear to me that $w_{1,j}$, $w_{2,j}$ are the variables, but if we are ultimately solving for the locations of schools $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, how will I end up finding $a,b,c,d$ if I’m solving for the number of students from each subdivision?  In other words, where do $a,b,c,d$ come from if they are not in the constraints?

I attempted to make up some schools and some numbers, trying to reverse engineer it a little but I'm stuck.  The reason I'm interested in this problem is because the school district in my home town is going through the process of drawing new boundaries and I have access to some relevant data and I thought it would be interesting.  Thanks in advance.